# Angular Chart.js not displaying Chart (Legend is Displaying)

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I am using the Angular-chart.js package:
http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/

When I load the page, the legend at the bottom of the page shows, but the chart itself is not displayed.

I added divs to verify that the data is actually populated.  Here is the code that I have so far:

```
<div>
    <span>
        vm.bvpsData - 
    </span>
    {{vm.bvpsData | json}}
</div>

<div>
    <span>
        vm.bvpsLabels - 
    </span>{{vm.bvpsLabels | json}}
</div>

<div>
    <span>
        vm.bvpsSeries - 
    </span>{{vm.bvpsSeries | json}}
</div>

<canvas id="bvpsChart" class="chart chart-line" data-data="vm.bvpsData"
        data-labels="vm.bvpsLabels" data-legend="true" data-series="vm.bvpsSeries">
</canvas>
```

When I run the page and look at the code, this is what is rendered in the html:

```
<div class="ng-binding"><span>vm.bvpsData -</span>[
  [
    "6.88",
    "6.95",
    "4.31",
    "4.33",
    "4.45",
    "4.49",
    "4.16",
    "4.04",
    "3.92",
    "3.61",
    "3.68",
    "3.55",
    "3.21",
    "3.38",
    "3.62",
    "3.98",
    "3.86",
    "3.66",
    "3.87",
    "4.15",
    "4.41",
    "4.59",
    "4.95",
    "5.15",
    "5.22",
    "5.40",
    "5.66",
    "6.28",
    "6.68",
    "7.00",
    "7.57",
    "8.08",
    "7.79",
    "8.10",
    "8.59",
    "9.10",
    "9.33",
    "9.68",
    "10.14",
    "10.45",
    "10.74",
    "10.80",
    "11.07",
    "10.94"
  ]
]</div>
<div class="ng-binding"><span>vm.bvpsLabels -</span>[
  "06/2004",
  "09/2004",
  "12/2004",
  "03/2005",
  "06/2005",
  "09/2005",
  "12/2005",
  "03/2006",
  "06/2006",
  "09/2006",
  "12/2006",
  "03/2007",
  "06/2007",
  "09/2007",
  "12/2007",
  "03/2008",
  "06/2008",
  "09/2008",
  "12/2008",
  "03/2009",
  "06/2009",
  "09/2009",
  "12/2009",
  "03/2010",
  "06/2010",
  "09/2010",
  "12/2010",
  "03/2011",
  "06/2011",
  "09/2011",
  "12/2011",
  "03/2012",
  "06/2012",
  "09/2012",
  "12/2012",
  "03/2013",
  "06/2013",
  "09/2013",
  "12/2013",
  "03/2014",
  "06/2014",
  "09/2014",
  "12/2014",
  "03/2015"
]</div>
<div class="ng-binding"><span>vm.bvpsSeries -</span>[
  "Book Value Per Share"
]</div>
<div class="chart-container">
    <canvas id="bvpsChart" class="chart chart-line ng-isolate-scope" data-data="vm.bvpsData" data-labels="vm.bvpsLabels" data-legend="true" data-series="vm.bvpsSeries" width="929" height="0" style="width: 929px; height: 0px;"></canvas>
    <chart-legend>
        <ul class="line-legend">
            <li><span style="background-color:rgba(151,187,205,1)"></span>Book Value Per Share</li>
        </ul>
    </chart-legend>
</div>
```

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Why is the chart not displaying?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem.  I had the chart canvas in a div with an ng-show and kept it hidden until a stock was selected.

I changed it to an ng-if and everything worked perfect after that.